# Вывод первых пяти элементов из массива

Tags: php, массивы

Вывожу первых 5 элементов массива (про функцию `array_slice` знаю, но хочу сделать без неё), но вместо **1,2,3,4,5** получаю **2,3,4,5**, а куда подевалась 1? Как исправить? Варианты с `array_slice` не предлагать.

```
$arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
for($i=0;$i<=count($arr);$i++){
    for($j=$arr[0];$j<$arr[4];$j++){
        echo $arr[$j];
    }break;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не понимаю всех этих сложностей. Нужно первые пять? почему тогда не вывести первые пять?

```
$arr = range(1,10);
for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++){
    echo $arr[$i];
}
```

ну или для ассоциативных

```
$arr = range(1,10);
$i   = 0;
foreach($arr as $val)
{
    if ($i++ == 5) break;
    echo $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ну, вы сами это себе придумали, воспользовавшись двумя циклами:

```
for($j=$arr[0];$j<$arr[4];$j++){
```

`$j` идет от `$arr[0]`, который равен единице, до `$arr[3]` - четверки. Другими словами, выполняется такой цикл:

```
for ($j = 1; $j < 5; $j++) {
     echo $arr[$j];
}
```

так как массив начинается с нулевого элемента, выводятся со второго по пятый.

Конечно, на самом деле вам нужен только один цикл

```
function arraySliceImplementation($array, $start, $length)
{
    $length = ($start + $length) < sizeof($array) ? $length : sizeof($array) - $start;
    $copy = [];
    for ($i = $start; $i < $start + $length; $i++) {
        $copy[] = $array[$i];
    }
    return $array;
}
```

(возможно, где-то ошибся с границами массива, у меня всегда с этим плохо)

Comment: ,ваш ответ как мне кажется слишком мудрен переписал вот   так,
       
      <pre>

      <code>

       $arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
       for($i=0;$i<=count($arr);$i++){
  for ($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
         echo $arr[$j];
       }
</pre> </code>